# wp_head(); not inserting my css into <head>

Tags: wordpress, xampp, wordpress-theming

First off, yes, I have used the search function.
No solution worked for me.

Running XAMPP 8.2.0, localhost.

**functions.php**

```
<?php
function add_CSS() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'gj-sheet', "/assets/css/style.css");
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_CSS');
?>
```

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <title>Jobs</title>
</head>
```

I need the stylesheet to be inserted in my .

Comment: Do you get any error/warning? Maybe you are missing something like `get_template_directory_uri()` if the CSS file is in your template folder?

Comment: Seems like changing my destination to /wp-content/themes/themename/assets/css/style.css has solved it.

Comment: That's why I asked, as far as I remember that's where functions.php is located and the path is relative (actually depends how PHP files are loaded, that's why using wordpress directory functions are really useful, they assure you the path is correct in any file anywhere)